Computation of the symmetric number of a finite group
I got a bit curious about the concept of the symmetric number of a finite group, and decided to do some computations with GAP to determine their values for some small finite groups. The symmetric number $S(G)$ of a finite group, $G$, is the least $n$ such that there exists a subgroup $K$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ such that $K\simeq G$. This number has some significance to groups actions where the acting group is $G$, particularly the set being acted upon must be at least this size for the action to be faithful.
One can readily prove both a lower and upper bound for this value based on $|G|$. The upper bound is an immediate corollary of Cayley's Theorem, which guarantees that $G$ can be realized as a subgroup of $S_n$ for $n=|G|$. A lower bound comes from the observation that in order for $S_n$ to have a subgroup $K$ with $|K|=|G|$, $|G|$ must divide the order of $S_n$, which is $n!$. Hence we require that $n$ be at least as large the least $n$ for which $|G|$ divides $n!$. This said, there is a non-trivial gap between these two bounds even for fairly small $n$, and the behavior of groups within this gap is interesting. One can prove some easily results for some special classes of groups without too much effort, but of course these don't generalize to all finite groups.
Working in GAP I have obtained a complete list of symmetric numbers for all finite groups of order up to 20. $S(n,i)$ is the symmetric number of the group of order $n$ with GAP library id (among groups of that order) $i$.
S(2,1)=2
S(3,1)=3
S(4,1)=4
S(4,2)=4
S(5,1)=5
S(6,1)=3
S(6,2)=5
S(7,1)=7
S(8,1)=8
S(8,2)=6
S(8,3)=4
S(8,4)=8
S(8,5)=6
S(9,1)=9
S(9,2)=6
S(10,1)=5
S(10,2)=7
S(11,1)=11
S(12,1)=7
S(12,2)=7
S(12,3)=4
S(12,4)=5
S(12,5)=7
S(13,1)=13
S(14,1)=7
S(14,2)=9
S(15,1)=8
S(16,1)=16
S(16,2)=8
S(16,3)=8
S(16,4)=8
S(16,5)=10
S(16,6)=8
S(16,7)=8
S(16,8)=8
S(16,9)=16
S(16,10)=8
S(16,11)=6
S(16,12)=10
S(16,13)=8
S(16,14)=8
S(17,1)=17
S(18,1)=9
S(18,2)=11
S(18,3)=6
S(18,4)=6
S(18,5)=8
S(19,1)=19
S(20,1)=9
S(20,2)=9
S(20,3)=5
S(20,4)=7
S(20,5)=9

Quite a few of these I could correctly predict with easy results (for example the cyclic group of prime order $p$ always symmetric number $p$, for the direct product $\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_q$ with $p$ and $q$ relatively prime, we have that the symmetric number is $p+q$, and for the dihedral groups, we have $S(G)\leq |G|/2$ by the obvious representation as the symmetries the regular $n$-gon among others), but some were surprising (especially S(16,9)).
My question is mostly if this has been looked into more and if so, what else is known about it. It seems particularly interesting from the standpoint of classifying possible faithful group actions for a given group.

Browse for "minimal (degree) faithful permutation representation",

$S(G)$ is usually denoted with $\mu(G)$.

$(16,9)$ is the generalized quaternion group of order $16$, also known as the dicyclic group of order $16$, see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Generalized_quaternion_group:Q16 – perhaps all the groups in this family have $S(n,i)=n$.

@GerryMyerson That's correct! It has been proved that the only finite groups $G$ with minimal permutation degree equal to $|G|$ are cyclic $p$-groups, the Klein $4$-group, and generalized quaternion groups.
